# How get First & Last occrance of table Row in SQl Server table

Tags: sql-server

```
Date         Speed
____________________
01/01/2015    20
02/01/2015    30
03/01/2015    40
04/01/2015    0
05/01/2015    0
06/01/2015    0
07/01/2015    10
08/01/2015    20
```

Need a Result like this (where speed=0)

```
First-OccurrenceDate  Last-OccurrenceDate
04/01/2015            06/01/2015
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: This clearly shows lack of research effort. Read on `MIN`, `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(Date) AS First-OccurrenceDate, MAX(Date) AS Last-OccurrenceDate
FROM   MYTABLE
WHERE  SPEED = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select min([Date]) as [First-OccurrenceDate], max([Date]) as [Last-OccurrenceDate]
from yourtablename
where speed = 0
```